# How to use BETWEEN and OR operator together in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, mssql-jdbc

I'm having issue with the sql query to filter the data between date range along with few conditions. Here is my query it is returning the data but `BETWEEN` date range isn't working as expected.

```
select CAL_DT as CALDATE,
sum (ORDER_PALL) as PALL, 
sum (ORDER_QTY) as UNI 
from [ORDER] 
where CAL_DT BETWEEN '2021-08-07' and '2021-08-16' or
TYPE IN ('MANUAL','SYSTEM') OR
GMM IN ('123','345') 
group by CAL_DT order by CAL_DT ASC
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
CALDATE       PALL    UNI

2021-08-04     200     50
2021-08-05     600     30
2021-08-06     300     20
2021-08-07     0       10
2021-08-08     700     90
2021-08-09     300     20
2021-08-10     700     10
```

**EXPECTED OUT PUT:**

```
CALDATE       PALL    UNI

2021-08-07     0       10
2021-08-08     700     90
2021-08-09     300     20
2021-08-10     700     10
```

My conditions `TYPE` and `GMM` could be null sometimes. That's why I want to use `OR`.

Comment: Why the tag for the SQL Server JDBC driver if you are using MySQL? Are you suing Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps you wanted to *and* together the criteria in your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT CAL_DT AS CALDATE,
       SUM(ORDER_PALL) AS PALL,
       SUM(ORDER_QTY) AS UNI
FROM [ORDER]
WHERE CAL_DT BETWEEN '20210807' AND '20210816' AND
      TYPE IN ('MANUAL', 'SYSTEM')
GROUP BY CAL_DT
ORDER BY CAL_DT;
```

Note: As you seem to be using SQL Server, not MySQL, you should use unambiguous date literals.  So use `'20210807'` rather than `'2021-08-07'`.

Comment: Actually I have multiple conditions like `TYPE` in where clause. Ex: `GMM IN ('123','456')`. These values might be null some times. Thats why I used `OR` operator. In that case query is not returning data as expected. Updated the question as well.